# How to convert an object that is a fraction to an integer in Python?

Tags: python

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '100/100'

My data set has a rating column that holds a rating in the form of an object presented as: 98/100, 99/100, 60/100, etc.

I need to convert this column to an int such as: 98, 99, 60, etc.

I tried `.astype` and `int(float())`.

Comment: how much do you trust that your text is "safe"? Is the value always out of "100"?

Comment: Strip the `/100` first; it's irrelevant noise for your purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account that:

1. You are talking about pandas dataframes
2. Each grade is in the form `X/100`, if not - then a basic computation can be done in the `lambda` function below.

you can use the `apply` method and then use the `astype` to convert the column to integer values:

```py
df = df['rating'].apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[0]).astype(int))
```

---

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'rating': ['90/100', '88/100', '35/100']})
df['rating'] = df['rating'].apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[0]).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   rating
0  90
1  88
2  35
```

---

The more generic computation if the grade is in the format `X/Y`:

```py
df['rating'] = df['rating'].apply(lambda x: (int(x.split('/')[0]) / int(x.split('/')[1])) * 100).astype(int)
```

Or shortly, but [**extremely unsafe**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) and not a good practice at all:

```py
df['rating'] = df['rating'].apply(lambda x: eval(x) * 100).astype(int)
```

You can use it if you're just "fiddling around" with Python :-)

Answer (score 2):

`'98/100'` is a string representing a fraction.

@no_hex's answer shows a way to parse the numerator using string operations.
However Python has also support for fractions, so it might be easier to use those.

```py
>> from fractions import Fraction
>> s = "98/100"
>> int(Fraction(s) * 100)
98
```

As a side benefit, this will also give the correct answer if the fraction denominator is different.

```py
>> s = "3/4"
>> float(Fraction(s) * 100)
75.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '60/100'
int(s.split('/')[0])
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

You will have to round it up to the nearest interger value and then you can cast it to a interger so for example 3/5 would be 0.6 but if you try cast that, it won't work since its a decimal value but if you round it up you can cast it to a interger

Also depends on what you'd like to do

Comment: I think the core issue is not math but how to parse the given strings

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try this code:

```
result = int(valueOfyoucolumn) * 100
```

By this, you are removing the fraction and you convert the results into an interger.

Comment: `valueOfyoucolumn` is a string, so `* 100` concatenates it with itself 100 times.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the edited code is still problematic. `int("60/100")` (for example) will give a ValueError.